# ArcGIS IOS load TPK from Shared Container AGSLocalTiledLayer

Tags: ios, arcgis-ios, swift

I have 2 apps that are trying to share the same TPK offline base map.  I have App Groups enabled and have the TPK file stored in the shared container but it does not seem to work when referencing the file with AGSLocalTiledLayer.

The error message I see says "Cache at path '(null)' not found"

Does anyone know if this approach is possible?

Comment: I have run in to the same problem. Backing up a step, I have the same problem when specifying a full path even to my own Documents directory. So AGSLocalTiledLayer:name: works, which looks for the file in the app bundle or app's Documents directory, but AGSLocalTiledLayer:path: does NOT work when I point it to the same file in the Document's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working. In my case, the problem was passing a proper path name without "file://" at the beginning. Using url.absolutePath does this, so you need to strip it off when converting URL's. Here is some sample code:

```
// Get a URL to the shared file location
func getSharedFilePath(appGroup:String)->URL? {

    if let directoryPath = FileManager().containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroup) {
        return directoryPath.appendingPathComponent(sharedFilename)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

public func writeToSharedFile(version:Int)->String {

    guard let fileURL = getSharedFilePath(appGroup:applicationGroup) else {
        return("Error getting shared file path")
    }

    guard !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) else {
        return("File already exists")
    }

    // get path to file in app bundle
    guard let tpkFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: appBundleFilename, withExtension: "tpk") else {
        return("Error finding file in app bundle")
    }

    // read file from app bundle to data variable
    var data:Data? = nil
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: tpkFile)
    } catch {
        print("Error saving file")
    }

    // write data variable to file in file system
    do {
        try data?.write(to: fileURL)
        print("Success: shared file saved: \(fileURL)")
    } catch {
        print("Error saving shared file")
    }

    return("ok")
}

public func readFromSharedFile()->String {

    guard let url = getSharedFilePath(appGroup:applicationGroup) else {
        return("Error getting shared file path")
    }

    // read file from file system to data variable
    var fullPath = url.absoluteString
    // strip off "file://"
    fullPath = fullPath.substring(from: fullPath.index(fullPath.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
    let basemap = AGSLocalTiledLayer(path: fullPath)    //old syntax

    if let error = basemap?.error {
        print("Read shared file error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        print("Read shared file loaded OK")
    }

    return("data file read successfully")
}
```